# Downscaling part of image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, resize, python-imaging-library

I am trying to downscaling part of image start from (x,y) coordinate and have a width and height of 500 to be resized to 40x40. By doing so, I am averaging the surrounding pixel into one. (the simplest way I could find) But result is weird.

The original image is a 512x512 png

Original Image:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

Actual Result:

[image]

Below is the code snippet:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


defined_size = 40
img = Image.open("lena.png")
pix = np.array(img)
changed_img = shrink(pix, 0, 0, 500)
changed_img = np.array(changed_img)
resized = Image.fromarray(changed_img, 'RGB')

def shrink(img, x, y, size):
     result = [[0 for width in xrange(defined_size)] for height in xrange(defined_size)] 

     scale_factor = size/defined_size    
     for i in xrange(defined_size):
        for j in xrange(defined_size):
            temp = np.array([0,0,0])
            for t in xrange(scale_factor):
                print img[i*scale_factor+x, j*scale_factor+y]
                temp = np.add(temp, img[i*scale_factor+x, j*scale_factor+y])
            result[i][j] = np.divide(temp, scale_factor)
            print result[i][j]

     return result
```

Comment: Can you post examples of before and after images? Saying "result is weird" doesn't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: @BrokenBinary I don't have enough reputation to post it though.

Comment: Both of those images are the same. Can you post the original as well?

Comment: You're not doing an average - you're adding the same pixel up `scale_factor` times, then dividing by `scale_factor`. Think harder about the pixels you need to sum for the average.

Comment: @BrokenBinary I suspect the original is this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna

Comment: I went ahead and embedded the images for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code.  Let's tackle the issues one at a time:

## Issue #1 - `(x,y)` are useless in your `shrink` definition

I see where you're going with `(x,y)`.  You're using this to traverse over each of the larger blocks, summing all of the pixels and dividing by the total number of entries to get the average RGB pixel.  You are setting this to `(0,0)` for every single block in the image, and so you aren't actually getting all of the pixels in the block.  You'll need to use a pair of `for` loops to allow you to traverse over each block.  I've also taken the liberty of removing the `(x,y)` inputs, and putting in the desired size as input into your function instead.

## Issue #2 - Output is not three-channel

You initialized a two-dimensional list, yet **the image has three channels**.  Because you're using `numpy` to do the computation for you... why don't you just declare an array of `zeros` via `np.zeros` first?  This way, you don't have to convert back to a `numpy` array when you're finished.  I've changed the declaration of your output image so that it's a `numpy` array of type `uint8`.  This casting is important!

## Issue #3 - Not iterating over each subsampled block properly

As we talked about with Issue #1, you aren't collecting the pixels properly per subsampled block.  I inserted another pair of `for` loops to do that for you... enumerated as `x` and `y`.  I've also removed `np.add` and used `+` to do the operations for you because it's easier to read.

## Issue #4 - Dividing by the wrong factor

Because it's an average of a subsample you are trying to calculate, you must divide by the total number of values within each block.  That is equal to `scale_factor*scale_factor`.  You were only dividing by `scale_factor`.

---

I've also taken the liberty to show the resized image and saving it to file.  Without further ado here's the corrected code.  I've also placed your testing code in a `__main__` block to make it easier for testing:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def shrink(img, size, defined_size): # Change - Issue #1
     result = np.zeros((defined_size, defined_size, 3), dtype=np.uint8) # Change - Issue #2

     scale_factor = size/defined_size    
     for i in xrange(defined_size):
        for j in xrange(defined_size):
            temp = np.array([0,0,0])
            for x in xrange(scale_factor): # Change - Issue #3
                for y in xrange(scale_factor): # Change - Issue #3    
                    temp += img[i*scale_factor + x, j*scale_factor + y] # Change - Issue #3

            result[i,j] = temp / (scale_factor*scale_factor) # Change          

     return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    img = Image.open("lena.png")
    pix = np.array(img)
    changed_img = shrink(pix, 512, 40) # Change - Issue #1
    resized = Image.fromarray(changed_img, 'RGB')
    resized.show() # Change
    resized.save("lena_resize.png")
```

... and we get this resized image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but x, y is for determine which part of the selected image to resize, not resizing the whole image. But yeah, it works!

Comment: @Mandary - That wasn't clear in your original post, but I'm glad it works nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

I have adapted the code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31101811/3250829) which will now resize an input image of any dimensions to a quarter of the size by averaging the surrounding pixels. The earlier version only worked for square images.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def quarter_res_avg(im):

    original_width = im.shape[1]
    original_height = im.shape[0]
    width = original_width / 4
    height = original_height / 4

    resized_image = np.zeros(shape=(height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    scale = 4

    for i in range(height):
        for j in range(width):
            temp = np.array([0, 0, 0])
            for x in range(scale):
                for y in range(scale):
                    temp += im[i*scale + x, j*scale + y]
            resized_image[i, j] = temp/(scale*scale)

    return resized_image

im = cv2.imread('Lenna_test_image.png', 1)
cv2.imwrite('Lenna_test_image_resized.png', quarter_res_avg(im))
```

Another way to do it:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def quarter_res_avg(im):

    original_width = im.shape[1]
    original_height = im.shape[0]

    width = original_width / 4
    height = original_height / 4

    resized_image = np.zeros(shape=(height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    scale = 4

    for i in range(0, original_height, scale):
        for j in range(0, original_width, scale):
           resized_image[i/scale, j/scale] = np.mean(im[i:i + scale, j:j+scale], axis=(0, 1))

    return resized_image
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a library function? Python libraries are awesome.

```
import PIL.Image
import scipy.misc

lena = scipy.misc.lena()
resized = scipy.misc.imresize(lena, (40, 40), interp='bilinear')
image = PIL.Image.fromarray(resized)
```

Comment: I would like to implement the averaging step and compare it with downsampling! So a library here does not help!